# Run Puppeteer with Tor

Tags: node.js, tor, puppeteer

I installed the Tor Expert Bundle and I would like to run it with Puppeteer.

I try:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false,args:['--proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:9050"']});
```

But I get the error ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES. I can run it with a normal Chrome browser.

Comment: Removing the double-quotes worked for me. i.e. `['--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050']`

Answer (score 13):

There's an opened bug in chromium regarding more complex configurations for proxy in headless mode ([Source](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=681521)). There has not been any activity since July 2017.

However, I've been able to run Puppeteer (1.3.0) with a headless chromium and SOCKS5 proxy configuration.

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:1337']});
```

Try updating Puppeteer, which also updates the bundled Chromium, and run again. Also seems like you might have a typo: remove the **"** between `socks5://127.0.0.1:9050`.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like puppetteer can only by run with proxy with no headless mode

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Running Puppeteer with Tor](https://medium.com/@jsilvax/running-puppeteer-with-tor-45cc449e5672).

```js
/**************************************************************************
 * IMPORTS
 ***************************************************************************/

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

/**************************************************************************
 * DEMOS > USING PUPPETEER BEHIND TOR
 * BASED ON https://medium.com/@jsilvax/running-puppeteer-with-tor-45cc449e5672
 ***************************************************************************/

;(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: ['--proxy-server=socks5://127.0.0.1:9050'],
    headless: false,
  })

  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.goto('https://check.torproject.org/')

  const isUsingTor = await page.$eval('body', (el) =>
    el.innerHTML.includes('Congratulations. This browser is configured to use Tor')
  )

  if (!isUsingTor) {
    console.log('Not using Tor. Closing...')
    return await browser.close()
  }

  console.log('Using Tor. Continuing... ')

  // Now you can go wherever you want
  await page.goto('https://www.facebook.com/')

  // You would add additional code to do stuff...

  // Then when you're done, just close
  await browser.close()
})()
```