# Python requests_html: Socks5h proxy does not work when calling "render()"

Tags: python, proxy, tor, socks, python-requests-html

I'm using "python requests_html" because I want to get the rendered html source code.
In addition, I want to do that via socks5h(Tor) proxy.

So, I tried to write the following code.
However, once render() function was called, raw ip address is displayed.
This seems that render() function doesn't use proxy settings.

Actually, I tried to connect to tor bbc news (onion domain) using the following code, it failed, because that's not tor network.

Is there any good idea to render using socks5h proxy?

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

url = "http://ifconfig.me/ip"
# url = "https://www.bbcnewsv2vjtpsuy.onion/" # bbc news
session = HTMLSession()

proxies = {"http": "socks5h://localhost:9150","https": "socks5h://localhost:9150"}
r = session.get(url, proxies=proxies)
content = r.html
print(content.text) # Tor’s IP will be displayed 

content.render()    # rendering for javascript, etc..
print(content.text) # Raw IP will be displayed
```

Error message when trying to access tor bbcnews site:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "requests_html_01.py", line
> 12, in 
> content.render()    # rendering for javascript   File "/home/testuser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_html.py",
> line 598, in render
> content, result, page = self.session.loop.run_until_complete(self._async_render(url=self.url,
> script=script, sleep=sleep, wait=wait, content=self.html,
> reload=reload, scrolldown=scrolldown, timeout=timeout,
> keep_page=keep_page))   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 484, in
> run_until_complete
> return future.result()   File "/home/testuser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests_html.py",
> line 512, in _async_render
> await page.goto(url, options={'timeout': int(timeout * 1000)})   File
> "/home/testuser/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyppeteer/page.py",
> line 879, in goto
> raise PageError(result) pyppeteer.errors.PageError: net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED at https://www.bbcnewsv2vjtpsuy.onion/

Comment: I think you need to read this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402502/run-puppeteer-with-tor

Comment: Thanks Abhishek!
I checked the url that you commented, after that I found similar posts. These posts say that this proxy issue depends on pyppeteer, and it'll be merged in the near future.
https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues/266
https://github.com/psf/requests-html/pull/396
Your comment was really helped! Could you please submit it as answer?

Comment: I don't think I should post a url as an answer. Glad, it helped you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the self answer.
requests_html uses pyppeteer internally, and this proxy issue depends on pyppeteer. Current requests_html seems that it doesn't pass proxy information, so   pyppeteer doesn't use proxy.
According to the following github pages, it seems that this issue would be solved in the future.

- https://github.com/psf/requests-html/issues/266
- https://github.com/psf/requests-html/pull/396